# Filter username field on registration for profanity and unwanted words

Tags: filters, user-registration, username

How do I add a filter to the username field to stop new users from registering using unwanted words such as `administrator` or general profanity?

Ideally, if I could add a large list of words that are blocked with the option to add asterisk (*) as a wildcard like `genitals*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two very different hooks you can use, depending on the installation:

- `wpmu_validate_user_signup` for multi-site and
- `registration_errors` for single-site.

The following *untested* code shows how to use them. You can tweak the array in `user_name_is_forbidden()` to your needs. Use regular expressions for the matches.

```
// multi-site
add_filter( 'wpmu_validate_user_signup', function( $result )
{
    // there is already an error
    if ( $result['errors']->get_error_message('user_name') )
        return $result;

    if ( user_name_is_forbidden( $result['user_name'] ) )
        $result['errors']->add('user_name',  __( 'That username is not allowed.' ) );

    return $result;
});

//single-site
add_filter( 'registration_errors', function( $errors, $name )
{
    if ( user_name_is_forbidden( $name ) )
        $errors->add('user_name',  __( 'That username is not allowed.' ) );
    return $errors;
}, 10, 2);


function user_name_is_forbidden( $name )
{
    // If you need the character '~', write it as '\~'.
    $forbidden = array(
        'admin.*',
        'genitals.*',
        'system.*'
    );

    return (bool) preg_match( '~' . join( '|', $forbidden ) . '~i', $name );
}
```

Comment: Just be careful what "bad words" filters you use. Some people like "shitake" mushrooms. Or are fans of "classic" music. Or come from a place called "scunthorpe".

Comment: @Otto Or they are from Essex. :)

Comment: That was devilish! Works great toscho!

Comment: Christine, I really wonder how much of your platform toscho already has built :D

Comment: @Otto A fun trivia. We just opened registrations and one new users registered with "ScatArt*..." - Just as we were hitting the ban button, we googled the email address of the user and it appears that it was a genuine registration, no trolling. As if!!