# Limit username to specific characters (A-Z and 0-9)

Tags: user-registration, limit, username, characters

How do I limit the username field upon registration to `A-Z` and `0-9` for single site? So no spaces, hyphens, underscores, dots etc.

Comment: Use the same solution as in [your last question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124584/73) and change the regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the regex posted by **Moaz** (and adding capitals), we will need to hook into the `registration_errors` filter:

```
// Restrict username registration to alphanumerics
add_filter('registration_errors', 'limit_username_alphanumerics', 10, 3);
function limit_username_alphanumerics ($errors, $name) {

 if ( ! preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}$/', $name) ){
    $errors->add( 'user_name', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Username can only contain alphanumerics (A-Z 0-9)','CCooper') );
 }
 return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Just a note that this also limits the characters between 3-16.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression

> /^[a-z0-9]{3,16}$/

(3,16) used for limit the characters

Comment: Out of the box, WordPress enforces a 3-character minimum on usernames. Your `{0,16}` should probably be `{3,16}` to reflect this reality. (I had to add a filter to allow a 2-character username.)